# .NET 4.x changes decimal mark as opposed to .NET 3.5 - how to fix it? (Unity)

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

So I started remaking my Unity project bottom up, with "Scripting runtime version" setting changed to ".NET 4.x Equivalent". Then I noticed my "float.Parse" removes decimal marks (dots) from strings (and vice versa).

Example:

```
string s1 = "10.2";
string s2 = "20,2";
Debug.Log("TEST PARSE 1: "+float.Parse(s1));
Debug.Log("TEST PARSE 2: "+float.Parse(s2));
```

.NET 3.5 returns:

> "TEST PARSE 1: 10.2"
>
> "TEST PARSE 2: 202"

.NET 4.x returns:

> "TEST PARSE 1: 102"
>
> "TEST PARSE 2: 20,2"

Now, this represents quite a problem for me, given that .NET version is the only thing changed (I can have two running projects giving out different results at the same time) - so it is not dependent on my other computer or Unity settings (unless changing this version makes some sneaky changes elsewhere in Unity without notifying me). Given that, how do I reproduce the first variant in .NET 4.x?

**EDIT**

**Here's a solution (the one posted is correct, but this will settle it for Unity specifically): In some script, just pass the following:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Threading;
 
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class Startup {
    static Startup() {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");
    }
}
```

Source: https://forum.unity.com/threads/editor-is-using-windows-locale-settings.442847/

Comment: It's probably culture related. Try using a culture: float.parse("10.2", CultureInfo.InvarantCulture). Or whatever is appropriate in your case.

Comment: Seems like in the configuration of your .Net 3.5 and 4.5 different float symbols.

Comment: This has to do with how globalization changed in .net4.x rather than anything to do with unity. I don't know the exact answer here but hopefully that'll point you in the right direction. My first hunch is be sure to set the culture on the thread if this is caused by users from various regions. If you intend to use in your code like this, you will likely need to do something with the parser

Comment: see my answer - setting the culture on the thread is a global solution to a very local problem (pun unintended)

Comment: What's new about .NET 4 is that it now pays attention to operating system overrides.  As configured in Control Panel > Language.

Comment: Second @JoshE on a global "solution" being a bad one.  Generally when you're dealing with input/output for the user it's nice to leave things in whatever culture they want to use; when doing input/output to file use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: @IceGlasses by "global solution" do you mean the one I edited into my question? Because yes, it would be nice for user to have a choice, but here I'm dealing with a piece of software (Unity) that can't make up it's mind to use this consistently - meaning, not implementing this global variant would bring my code into conflict with their native UI elements which are locked into working one specific way (until some future version I suppose).

Comment: @MrQuestions Then maybe it's appropriate for this situation.  However without explanation it seems that the `[InitializeOnLoad]` and/or `Startup` are the reason the edit is Unity-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is likely because in some culture sets, the `,` is used instead of the `.` in decimals.

If your current culture setting is, say, `en-US` and you execute this statement:

`float.Parse("20,2", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float)`

You'll throw a FormatException. If you swap `Float` with `Any` you'll get your desired result of `202`:

`float.Parse("20,20", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any) //2020`

ed: previous versions of .NET made a more generous assumption of intent than .NET 4.x, which is why you saw the behavior you observed.

ed 2: to be more specific, .NET 3.5 defaulted the single-parameter overload of `float.Parse` to `NumberStyles.AllowThousands` (or similar combo). This can allow a developer to introduce subtle defects resulting from culture settings and parsing of potentially ambiguous strings like this one:

`10,000 <--- is it 10 thousand, 10 point 000, etc?`

Comment: I'm not at en-US so that's probably why with "System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any" it returns the same (102 and 20,2). But in either case I understand what you're going for. But that's tad too much for me to fix at this point, so I'll just revert to 3.5 (used 4 solely for dynamic anyway).

Comment: what's preventing you from using the overload of float.parse? seems like it's a low-risk even if there's a lot of instances, you can always find/replace. I would not revert back to 3.5 if you can at all help it. There are many other improvements that you will sorely miss

Comment: That's an interesting solution, will give it a go (once I discover the correct argument to pass in Parse)

Comment: Scratch that, this problem is more extensive than that when it comes to Unity. When passing a string into InputField set to accept DecimalNumber, it will automatically delete dot, but only accept dot as input. Reverting to 3.5 is the easier solution here IMO.

Comment: IIRC, you can `|` number styles together to combine options. you try `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint`?

Comment: Just in case you're interested I found a unity-specific solution to this problem, edited in OP